# Docker container cannot write on volume

Tags: docker

I have a container for which I only have the image, and no Dockerfile. I'm running this container in a Centos7 VM. The container is started with:

```
docker run -it -v /mydir:/data container_image bash
```

This is Centos7 so there is some SELinux, but normally everything is writable:

```
# file: mydir
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::rwx
```

But in the bash session in the container:

```
bash-4.3# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1(bin),2(daemon),3(sys),4(adm),6(disk),10(wheel),11(floppy),20(dialout),26(tape),27(video)
bash-4.3# ls -ald /data
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root            20 Apr 30 15:28 /data
bash-4.3# touch /data/somefile
touch: /data/somefile: Permission denied
bash-4.3# mkdir /data/somedir
mkdir: can't create directory '/data/somedir': Permission denied
```

So, I am root, the directory is shown as universally writable, and yet I can't write to it...

Baffled.

PS: /data is really the right directory on the host, I put a marker file in it on the host, and I see the marker in the container.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem is indeed with SELinux, which has its specific handling for containers, as described [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html/container_security_guide/docker_selinux_security_policy). Since this is only for tests and I can't spend the time require to understand SELinux, the fix was to temporarily disable SELinux, as shown [here](https://www.tecmint.com/disable-selinux-temporarily-permanently-in-centos-rhel-fedora/).